# iOS Storyboard Conditionally showing Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am currently working on a project for the iPad using Storyboards for the 1st time and I am wondering if my approach is the correct way to do this.

The first ViewController in this example is actually a split view controller.

Currently within the iPad app when a user clicks on the Export Features Button I am conditionally requesting the segue based on some code / checks I am running

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"subscribe" sender:self];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filterOptions" sender:self];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showExportedDoc" sender:self];
```

However I am not sure if I should have 3 navigation controllers and also when a user clicks on the Buy button in the subscribe View Controller it pushes to the Filter Options View which is actually nested in another Navigation Controller.

Any help / advice on this would be great as I mention I am just not sure if I am following the best approach with this.

Thanks

[image: Storyboard Layout]

Comment: I'm not sure about your overall structure but you have a problem with #1 going to #2, and then #2 going back to #1. You shouldn't go back to a controller you came from unless you use an unwind segue, or go back in code (by dismissing or popping). Each time you do a segue, you're creating a new instance of the controller you're going to.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply I have updated the screen shot as the wording was incorrect.   The #1 going to #2 and vice versa was definitely the part I was not sure about especially with it skipping the navigation controller which it originated from

Comment: You have to mind that all segue will instantiate new view controller so when you trying to go back it won'b be a same view controller that you came from.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and
>   also when a user clicks on the Buy button in the subscribe View
>   Controller it pushes to the Filter Options View which is actually
>   nested in another Navigation Controller.

Well, I think you have some misunderstanding here. The fact that the filter options view controller is embedded within a navigation controller in your storyboard doesn't mean that it will be instantiated with the `UINavigationController` when you're pushing it within the current navigation controller (It will be so though if you connect the segue to the `UINavigationController` that it's embedded into).

To answer your original question, I don't see right and wrong approach here. It all depends on the structure you would like to have. For me, I guess I would prefer to have only one `UINavigationController` that manages everything (set it as an initial view controller and embed your home view controller within it). This would provide a more consistent navigation experience to the user, plus more consistent look (navigation bar would be shown from the beginning).